# Angular velocity of a rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia, angular-velocity

[image]

Hello, so I've been struggling with part b of this problem. The answer I got online for part b is that the angular velocity of the rod is still the same even after the rings have left the rod. But once the rings have left the rod, wouldn't the moment of inertia of the system decrease, and therefore the angular velocity increase due to conservation of angular momentum?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The rings that fly off retain the same angular momentum they had right before they flew off so that the total angular momentum remains the same without the rod speeding up. Once the rod is by itself it would require a torque that does not exist to change the rate of rotation of the rod.

Comment: let's write the angular momentum of the system at any instant about the centre of mass of the rod then $L=I_{r} \omega + 2m\omega x^{2}$ where $x$ is the separation between either ring's centre and the rod's centre. At separation **$x=\frac{l}{2}$** till that time there is a non zero torque on the system but after that ? what torque are you talking about @Bill Watts (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/219138/bill-watts)

Comment: There is no torque on the system at any time @AdityaGarg

Comment: then maybe my equation is wrong , coz it suggests something else ! I will look into that surely tho

Comment: quoting you "Once the rod is by itself it would require a torque that does not exist to change the rate of rotation of the rod" ? care to explain that too to me

Comment: @AdityaGarg When the rings fly off, the rod is by itself.  Since there is no torque on that rod, there will be no change in its rate of rotation.  The SYSTEM for which angular momentum is conserved, still includes the rings even after they fly off.